# Sitecore losing the client session unexpectedly

Tags: session-state, authentication

On my Sitecore instance I'm authenticating a user programatically like this(adapted for this post):

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult MyAction(MyModel model)
        {
             //custom logic
             Sitecore.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationManager.Login("extranet\\"+username,password);
        }
```

This works well. When I call the `Sitecore.Context.User.IsAuthenticated` property to check whether the user was authenticated it returns true.
But that lasts until the ActionResult finishes it's execution.  When I make a post or redirect the user to another page the IsAuthenticated property always returns false.

For example I have a post which gets executed on the same page declared as:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult MyAction(MyModel model, string anotherParameter)
        { 
               //This always returns false
               if (Sitecore.Context.User.IsAuthenticated)
               {
                    //my custom logic. 
               }

        }
```

This is what my session state looks on the web.config

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="20" sessionIDManagerType="Sitecore.SessionManagement.ConditionalSessionIdManager">
  <providers>
    <add name="mongo" type="Sitecore.SessionProvider.MongoDB.MongoSessionStateProvider, Sitecore.SessionProvider.MongoDB" sessionType="Standard" connectionStringName="session" pollingInterval="2" compression="true" />
    <add name="mssql" type="Sitecore.SessionProvider.Sql.SqlSessionStateProvider, Sitecore.SessionProvider.Sql" sessionType="Standard" connectionStringName="session" pollingInterval="2" compression="true" />
  </providers>
</sessionState>
```

As far as I can tell this is fine and should make the session last for 20 minutes.

Any thoughts on what could be wrong here?

Comment: Can you check the id of Tracker.Current.Contact.ContactId on the get and the post. I think you are sending two different sessions to these calls.

Comment: Both have the same guid
{f82c65fd-9111-45eb-b904-dd2a4f8b1286}

Comment: This are API calls or traditional MVC form controllers?

Comment: Traditional Sitecore controller MVC renderings

Comment: Is this happening locally or only in a scaled environment?

Comment: Check that ".ASPXAUTH" cookie is present in your post or redirect request is present.

Comment: this happens on a local environment

Comment: ASPXAUTH is present after authentication

Answer (score 2):

Try to pass the persistent paramenter:

```
Sitecore.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationManager.Login("extranet\\" + username, password, persistent: true, allowLoginToShell: false);
```

Comment: This didn't fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

Sitecore asynchronously checks for robot detection and everything goes well then it reset the session according to your configuration.

Please observe on your first request, Sitecore will make an ajax request to check something, it this not happening properly then you have to figure out why this is not happening 
please check that visitor identification is working properly.

Probably sitecore will make request `"/layouts/system/VisitorIdentificationCSS.aspx"`

Comment: what you mean by "Please observe on your first request, Sitecore will make an ajax request to check something"?
I haven't seen this happening as part of the request

Comment: Sitecore by default set ASP.Net session to 1 min for all users. Once Page is visited It makes a ajax cal to reset the session for 20 min /specified duration . Sitecore is doing this to detect the robots calls . You may also check the "Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.config" there you will see a setting for default session .

Comment: Observation - First checke Visital identification is enabled or not . 
make sure below code is added in your layout -
@using Sitecore.Mvc.Analytics.Extensions 

@Html.Sitecore().VisitorIdentification()

Clear cache -> open consol ,check requests , you will see a request "/layouts/system/VisitorIdentificationCSS.aspx" or any other similar request

Comment: I have manually increased the session time on Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.config to 15 minutes for example, and I do have the VisitorIdentification set on the layout. But still the session is getting cleared. When I post I see on the first line of the post method that the isAuthenticated is set to false